# I want to show just the expoent of the scientifi notation

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the image below that I generated using matplotlib. As you can see, on both axes scientific notation appears. I would like to control them so that I can customize this and make only the exponents appear.

In the case of the x axis, for example, instead of [1e2, 1e3, 1e4, 1e5] I would like to make [2, 3, 4, 5] appear

[image]

Comment: Can you think of a mathematical rule that, given `1e2` etc., would result in `2` etc.? What happens if you try using that rule to transform the x-coordinate values before creating the graph?

Comment: yes I can, but I want to know if I can use matplotlib to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Axes.set_xticklabels()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels.html). For some reason the `labels` argument for `Axes.set_xticks()` doesn't work for subplots.

```py
import math
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = [100.0, 1000.0, 10000.0, 100000.0]
y = np.arange(4) + 1

ax.loglog(x, y)
ticks = ax.get_xticks()
ax.set_xticks(ticks)  # seems pointless but eliminates FixedFormatter warning
ax.set_xticklabels(np.round(np.log10(ticks)).astype(int))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: `np.log10` might be an alternative to `math.log` and the list comprehension.